# fancytree drag n drop node revert back to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancytree

How do you make a node in fancytree revert back to it's original position after being dragged to a new place in the tree, for example after dropping the node to a new position I would have a confirmation dialog yes or no to move the object if the user says no it reverts back so in the drop there needs to be a move to a new destination shown but also have the confirmation and revert back yes or no. Or on drag start get the position and on drag drop revert to original position

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
extensions: ["dnd"],

// .. other options...

dnd: {
  autoExpandMS: 400,
  draggable: { // modify default jQuery draggable options
    zIndex: 1000,
    scroll: false,
    containment: "parent",
    revert: "invalid"
  },
  preventRecursiveMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes on own descendants
  preventVoidMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes 'before self', etc.

  dragStart: function(node, data) {
    // This function MUST be defined to enable dragging for the tree.
    // Return false to cancel dragging of node.
    //    if( data.originalEvent.shiftKey ) ...          
    //    if( node.isFolder() ) { return false; }
    return true;
  },
  dragEnter: function(node, data) {
    return true;
  },
  dragExpand: function(node, data) {
    // return false to prevent auto-expanding data.node on hover
  },
  dragOver: function(node, data) {
  },
  dragLeave: function(node, data) {
  },
  dragStop: function(node, data) {
  },
  dragDrop: function(node, data) {
    // revert node to back to it's original place
    data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
  }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've worked in fancytree, so I don't know the full details, but I think I can come up with an idea that might work:

When dropping your node, you should do 2 actions:

- Persist your original position in node.data (node.data.prevParent = node.parent() or prevSibling if you want to keep the position in the siblings)
- Fire off your dialog with your 2 options and pass the node reference

Your dialog basicly has 2 options:

- Accept: delete node.data.prevParent and close the dialog
- Reject: retrieve node.data.prevParent and move the node as a new child/sibling. Close the dialog afterwards

I hope this helps out a bit. Just in case you haven't found it: This also helps: [fancytree documentation](http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/)